# Magento attributes won't save - buttons disabled

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I've suddenly started having an odd problem, not something I've seen in Magento before.
I'm trying to add a new attribute called 'Brand', which will contain a list of Manufacturers for the client to select one from when creating a new product.
The problem is, as soon as I start to add the attribute values, e.g. Sony, Panasonic, Philips etc., and click the 'Save' or 'Save and continue' button, the two buttons are greyed out. Neither the attribute or its values get saved.

This has only just started to happen - it worked fine last week.

The version of Magento is 1.6.2

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)   ...In this case, we will need to know what changed since last week..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, *nothing* has changed since last week. This is what's so confusing. Last week I could add attributes with no problem, this week I can't.

I wondered if the problem was to do with some setting on the hosting. Another forum suggested the problem might be to do with the max_input_vars php.ini parameter, which was set to '5000'. I doubled it, but it made no difference.
The buttons are still being 'greyed out' when I try to save an attribute.
Here are the steps to reproduce the error.
1. Create a new attribute: Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add new attribute
2. Enter information:
Attribute code: brand
Scope: gloabl
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Dropdown
Default Value: NULL
Unique value: No
Values required: No
Input validation for Store Owner: None

### Apply To: All product types

Use in Quick Search: Yes
Use in Advanced Search: Yes
Comparable on Front-end: Yes
Use In Layered Navigation: Filterable (with results)
Use In Search Results Layered Navigation: Yes
Use for Promo Rule Conditions: No
Position: NULL
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end: Yes
Used in Product Listing: Yes
Used for Sorting in Product Listing: Yes

The on Manage Label/Options tab:
Manage Title: Admin: Brand
              English: Brand
              French: Marque
              German: Marke

Click 'Add option' button.
Admin/English/French/German: Acuvue
Position: 1
Is Default: Yes

Click orange 'Save attribute' button. 
Both 'Save Attribute' and 'Save and Continue Edit' buttons become disabled (greyed out).

Screenshot image:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sanmn.jpg)

Please can anyone help?